# Angular Protractor - How to debug variables

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

Consider the following code snippet

```
var allRows = element.all(by.repeater('row in items'))
```

This returns an `array` of repeater items. So, how do I debug this variable in console. When I do `console.log(allRows)`, I get the following in console not the array with `html`.

```
{ ptor_: { controlFlow: [Function],
 schedule: [Function],
 setFileDetector: [Function],
 getSession: [Function],
 getCapabilities: [Function],
 quit: [Function],
 actions: [Function],
 touchActions: [Function],
 executeScript: [Function],
 executeAsyncScript: [Function],
 call: [Function],
 wait: [Function],
 sleep: [Function],
 getWindowHandle: [Function],
 getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
 getPageSource: [Function],
 close: [Function],
 getCurrentUrl: [Function],
 getTitle: [Function],
 findElementInternal_: [Function],
 findElementsInternal_: [Function],
 takeScreenshot: [Function],
 manage: [Function],
 switchTo: [Function],
 driver: 
  WebDriver {
    session_: [Object],
    executor_: [Object],
    flow_: [Object],
    fileDetector_: null },
 element: { [Function] all: [Function] },
 '$': [Function],
 '$$': [Function],
 baseUrl: '',
 rootEl: 'html',
 ignoreSynchronization: false,
 getPageTimeout: 100000,
 params: {},
 ready: 
  Promise {
    flow_: [Object],
    stack_: null,
    parent_: null,
    callbacks_: null,
    state_: 'fulfilled',
    handled_: true,
    value_: null,
    queue_: null },
 plugins_: 
  { pluginConfs: [],
    pluginObjs: [],
    assertions: {},
    resultsReported: false },
 resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
 trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
 mockModules_: [ [Object] ],
 allScriptsTimeout: 100000,
 getProcessedConfig: [Function],
 forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
 restart: [Function] },
```

So how do I debug the actual variable which should contain all the html rows. I couldn't find the option for it in the debugging [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

`allRows` have the following markup.

```
<li>AA</li><li>BB</li><li>CC</li>
```

I need to view the entire thing in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `getOuterHtml()` -- which will print out the entire element tag (html attributes included) of the specified element.  For example,

```
it('prints element', function () {
    var el = element(by.model('username'));
    el.getOuterHtml().then(function (val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

This produces:

[image: this console output]

Source:https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getOuterHtml

Comment: He's starting from an element array. Using `allRows.getOuterHtml()` produces comma separated results in my console, not the described desired output.

Comment: Sure it's not a pretty log but that would tell him what elements he's grabbing - which sounds to me like exactly what he is asking for "the actual variable which should contain all the html rows".  Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Gunderson - This is exactly what I need. Thank You!

Comment: @TheHeadRush - Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that pretty much every Protractor function returns a promise which must be resolved before proceeding. If you want to see the contents of your variable `allRows`

```
allRows.each(function(row)getInnerHtml().then(function(html) {
     console.log(html);
});
```

Promises can be resolved in an expect method, so given that the expected result is referenced by the variable `myHtmlString` you could shorten the above to:

```
expect(allRows.getInnerHtml()).toBe(myHtmlString);
```

Response to Update:

What you want is the innerHtml of the parent element. You could get it with xpath functions, but they are the slowest selection method and, as such, should only be used as a last resort. If you could get the / directly, then the code i have provided will work. If, for some reason, you cannot get the list element directly, then

```
var firstItem = allRows.first();
var parent = firstItem.element(by.xpath('..'));
parent.getInnerHtml().then(function(html) {
    console.log(html);
});
```

should print the desired result in the console.

Comment: Thank You! But this only get the inner html, let `allRows` be an array of `<li><li>`, this only gets the text. I need the whole object value. Can we see that in console

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "the whole object value". If you can edit your post to add the snippet contained in `allRows` and what you want to extract out of it, i'll update my answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. I just need to view the variable with html markup in console. Something like allRows.getHtml() will print the whole markup in console.